# GraphQL : return new Promise((resolve,object)

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I've tried to figure it out myself, and google around, but i can't seem to find the answer anywhere, so I'll try my luck here.

I have this mutation, as below:

```
Mutation :{

            createFriend: (root,{ input }) => {

                const newFriend = new Friends({

                    firstName: input.firstName,
                    lastName: input.lastName,
                    gender: input.gender,
                    age: input.age,
                    language: input.language,
                    email: input.email,
                    contacts: input.contacts
                });

                newFriend.id = newFriend._id;

                return new Promise((resolve,object) =>{

                    newFriend.save((err) =>{

                        if(err) reject(err)
                        else resolve(newFriend)


                    })


                })
            }
```

What confuses me is the following snippet:

```
return new Promise((resolve,object) =>{

                newFriend.save((err) =>{

                    if(err) reject(err)
                    else resolve(newFriend)


                })


            }
```

What does "return new promise" do, and why does it have an object parameter inside, which i never seems to use?

Would be more than happy if someone could explain me what is going on.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks simply like a mistake. That `object` parameter should be named `reject`.

Comment: "*What does `return new promise` do*" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Had the same thought, but it works and it's from a Lynda tutorial, where the teacher keeps putting that object inside all his mutations.

Comment: @Bergi I know, but the site you are referring to,  has no examples of an object inside the parameter. However, it has plenty of examples using resolve,reject.

Comment: I'll go with your solution Bergi, and agree that it must be a mistake. Thank you for the help guys.

Comment: It's not "an object". It's just a parameter (of the function expression that you pass) named `object`, one could name it anything else. One could even keep using the name `object` and then call the function `if (err) object(err)`, it's just against convention. Btw, if the teacher is repeatedly doing this one should tell them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Bergi in the comments, it must be a mistake from teacher from the Lynda.com tutorial.

(resolve,reject) makes sense and it still works, so i'll close this question and say that Bergis answer is the solution.